# ¿Como crear un hotspot, mientras estoy conectado a internet por wifi?

Tags: ubuntu, redes, networking, wifi, yaml

Buen dia.

Necesito configurar un hotspot o un punto de acceso y al mismo tiempo estar conectado a internet por una red wifi.

Ya puedo crear el hotspot solo, y el hotspot con una conexión ethernet.

Si tuviera dos interfaces wifi no tendria problema, pero solo cuento con una.
Estoy usando Ubuntu 18.04 y para las configuraciones estoy usando archivos yaml en Netplan.

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: yes
  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      optional: yes
      access-points:
        "Red_camara":
          password: "R3D0C4M3RA"
          mode: ap
```

Utilizo esta configuración para tener red por ethernet y el  hotspot.

Comment: Tal vez [esta respuesta](https://askubuntu.com/a/1324852) sirva. Básicamente es usar `hostapd` como daemon y `create_ap` como utilidad pa configurar eso. De ahí en adelante es cosa de que el driver que tengas lo soporte...

Comment: @Alfabravo muchas gracias, el `create_ap` de esa respuesta ya no esta teniendo soporte, pero encontre un proyecto que si continua y es exacto lo que necesito.

Comment: Puedes ponerlo tú mismo como respuesta acá abajo. En unas horas puedes marcarla como respuestas aceptada y todo, así otros en el futuro sabrán que funciona :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución fue usar un proyecto llamado `create_ap`

La respuesta fue dada por @Alfabravo, me proporciono la siguiente [solución](https://askubuntu.com/a/1324852), que utiliza el proyecto [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap), sin embargo ya no le estan dando soporte, de ahi segui un proyecto en curso [Linux Wifi Hotspot](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot) que ya tiene mas mejoras y una interfaz grafica.

Solo instale hostapd

```
apt-get install hostapd
```

Descargue el git del proyecto e instale

```
git clone https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot
```

Solo instale la parte de linea de comandos

```
cd linux-wifi-hotspot/src/scripts
make install
```

E inicie el hotspot con el comando

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

`wlan0` es la interfaz inalambrica y `eth0` la interfaz desde donde se comparte el internet, puede ser la misma interfaz inalambrica o puede omitirse con la opcion `-n` sin indicar la segunda interfaz.

Comment: ese programa necesita de dos interfaces de red. Windows solo necesita de una para recibir el internet y compartirlo como hotspot.